# Security issue with form action $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php

I read that there is a potential security issue with forms like this (action `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`)

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Suchen">
</form>
```

Could someone explain how this could be manipulated? Could this somehow turn into a security issue? I personally use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` as action for form actions on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the following:

```
    http://www.example.com/foo.php/">script>alert('hello');/script>
```

It will still load your page but also include it within the output as well.

```
    form method="POST" action="/foo.php/">alert('hello');/script>">
        
    /form>
```